# Regarding how MVC and ViewModels are used

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-4, razor, viewmodel

I have Model POCOs that just store the usual information from the user and is used to submit and pre-populate the form elsewhere.

I have ViewModels(is this the right term?) that populate dropdownlists, sometimes by gathering information from XML configuration.

I combine all these classes into one superclass that is passed back to the page so that I can use razor syntax to pre-populate form data and form elements.

Am I doing this correctly? Is this how these things are supposed to be used? Coming from a webforms background it seems MVC gets really complicated to do the simplest things.  Granted, separating concerns and shortening code makes it much more maintainable.

Any general advice is welcome! Thanks!

EDIT 3/10/15:
Here's some code to illustrate what I mean:

```
//Models
public class FormData
{ 
    public int PersonID { get; set; }
    public string ItemName { get; set; }
}

public class FormElements
{
    public IEnumerable<SelectListItem> getSelectList (string DropdownListDesired)
    {
        //... get selectlist from XML config with linq
        return query;
    }
}

public class FormViewBag
{
    public FormViewBag
    {
        DataOnForm = new FormData();
        ElemOnFOrm = new FormElements();
    }
    public FormData DataOnForm { get; set; }
    public FormElements ElemOnForm { get; set; }
}

//Controller Method
[HttpGet]
public ActionResult Index()
{
    FormViewBag ViewBagOnForm = new FormViewBag();
    return View(ViewBagOnForm);
}

//CSHTML
@Html.DropDownListFor(m => m.FormData.ItemName, Model.FormElements.getSelectList("FavoriteRedStaplers"))
```

I understand this code might be way off and completely misguided, but I'd like to find out why.
As you can see, I'm assuming when you bind a view to a model, it's basically one object that you customize, instead of using the ViewBag directly.
New-ing up objects within the constructor of FormViewBag might be unnecessary, but let me know some alternatives.

Comment: try posting some code. if you have a lot of code to be reviewed, try http://codereview.stackexchange.com

Comment: It's impossible to tell because you are really vague, and are using terms in most likely incorrect ways.  Your best bet would be to show examples of what you mean.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your ViewModel should be the only object passed back to the page. The ViewModel may contain your Model POCO's as well as other objects you might need to use, such as data used to populating drop down lists.  The page should be bound to the ViewModel class, which will enable you to use the Razor Intellisense.

EDIT 2015/03/10
I like to keep it simpler.  It seems like you are going way to far in trying to make everything generic.

```
public class MyViewModel
{
    public int PersonID { get; set; }
    public string ItemName { get; set; }
    public IEnumerable<SelectListItem> selectListItems { get; set; }
}

//Controller Method
[HttpGet]
public ActionResult Index()
{
    MyViewModel model = new MyViewModel();
    model.PersonID = 0;
    model.ItemName = string.Empty;
    model.selectListItems = getSelectListItems();
    return View(model);
}

protected IEnumerable<SelectListItem> getSelectListItems ()
{
    //... get selectlist from XML config with linq
    return query;
}
```

Comment: Thanks, so it seems like I'm on the right track, just putting too much in terms of making it more complicated with extra formdata/formmodel classes.